# How can I select 2 different random rows from a table?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, sqlalchemy, pyramid

right now I have

```
row=session.query(Item).order_by(func.random()).limit(2)
name1=row[0].name
name2=row[1].name
```

Which gives me the first column(name) of each entry. The problem is, I get multiples (it will select the same random row twice. I want it to always be different. Is there a way to do this without an if, then statement?

if its useful, when I print row, it gives me something like this:

```
SELECT items.id AS items_id, items.name AS items_name, items.data AS items_data FROM items ORDER BY random() LIMIT ? OFFSET ?
```

why would it say limit ? I have put in limit(2)

Comment: Do you get an error when you say LIMIT 2 ?

Comment: umm Im not sure. Where would I specifically define LIMIT 2. I thought I was doing so through my view code with the limit(2) at the end of the query

Comment: Check the soln I posted..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that using order_by on func.random() is a bad idea in SQL (http://www.webtrenches.com/post.cfm/avoid-rand-in-mysql). Instead, I counted the length of the table, found 2 random numbers with in this length, and then queried the table to find the rows associated with these random numbers. Apparently this is faster. At least it doesn't have any repeats :)

```
number=session.query(func.count(Item.id)).scalar()
randoms=random.sample(range(number),2)
item1=session.query(Item).filter_by(id=randoms[0]+1).one()
item2=session.query(Item).filter_by(id=randoms[1]+1).one()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT items.id AS items_id, items.name AS items_name, items.data AS items_data
FROM items
ORDER BY random()
LIMIT 2;
```

Check the below link for reference.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_limit_clause.htm

Comment: so are you saying that the .limit(2) part is not working and thats why  It is picking the same entry twice?

Comment: but even if the limit is not working and it returns the entire table. Why would there be duplicate entries?

Comment: Instead of random() function why don't you use WHERE ROWNUM<=2 if you need any two random records.

Comment: I can't find much info on ROWNUM. Seems to be oracle database specific?

Comment: @SOaddict ROWNUM does not exist in sqlite. You have to use LIMIT. Without using random(), the output is most likely quite stable...