# Inconsistent behavior with sqlalchemy row update from form submission on sqlite3 database

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy, pyramid

Currently I have a table in my database with id, name (str), and data (int) columns. There is an html radio button form where selecting one button adds 1 to the corresponding entry in the database:

```
length_table=session.query(func.count(Item.id)).scalar()
randoms=random.sample(range(length_table),2)
item1=session.query(Item).filter_by(id=randoms[0]+1).one()
item2=session.query(Item).filter_by(id=randoms[1]+1).one()

if request.POST.get('myradiobutton') == "left":
    item1.data+=1
    return HTTPFound(location=request.route_url('sorting'))

if request.POST.get('myradiobutton') == "right":
    item2.data+=1
    return HTTPFound(location=request.route_url('sorting'))
```

This works but it has some shoddy behavior (sometimes adds to the right item and sometimes adds to the wrong item). Because I am using [pyramid_tm](http://pylons.readthedocs.org/projects/pyramid_tm/en/latest/) that should take care of the commits. The SQL log gives me:

```
SELECT rowid, *  FROM items ORDER BY rowid; 
SELECT name, sql FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' ;
PRAGMA TABLE_INFO(items);
SELECT name, sql FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='index'
```

There are no Update statements which is strange to me. How can the database be updated if non are issued? I believe that the updates should happen on the transaction.commit() line.

Here is the table definition:

```
class Item(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'items'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(Text, unique=True)
    data = Column(Integer)

    def __init__(self, name, data):
        self.name = name
        self.data = data
```

And this is where the engine is created:

```
def main(argv=sys.argv):
    if len(argv) != 2:
        usage(argv)
    config_uri = argv[1]
    setup_logging(config_uri)
    settings = get_appsettings(config_uri)
    engine = engine_from_config(settings, 'sqlalchemy.')
    DBSession.configure(bind=engine)
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

Comment: I don't get it: you are doing filtering by randomly generated numbers and are wondering why your code has non-deterministic behavior. But I don't really understand the code well enough to comment on what's going on exactly.

Comment: yeah its strange. I tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19507467/how-can-i-select-2-different-random-rows-from-a-table but you can read why I changed it

Comment: Just output the query you are running to see the actual SQL you're sending to the DB. Then compare that query against the data in the DB. The answer will be pretty obvious

Comment: I am not great with SQL statement. I have attached the SQL log to the question. Maybe this shows why its not working properly?

Comment: @BigBoy1337: Can you try to break this question (and future  questions) down more? Even if you are hazy with SQL, you should at least be able to test to ensure that the form is getting the correct values to the view function by adding some prints. If that doesn't work, fix it. If that part does work, then take the code for "pulling two records and incrementing one of them", and put this logic into its own function. Then, make your StackOverflow question about that function. You (and we) can then focus on what you're trying to do with SQLAlchemy.

Comment: Also, you do not seem to be committing your transaction. Are you using the ZopeTransactionExtension (which commits for you automatically at the end of the reuqest), or have you just forgotten to [commit()](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/session.html#committing)?

Comment: I have added the transaction commits yet the strange behavior still exists. A large problem in the beginning was that I forgot to redirect the user anywhere after form submission. I just fixed that and some of the strange behavior went away but not all. I will work on breaking down the question.

Comment: @MarkHildreth I have tried to break down the question to its bare bones without changing it too much. Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: @BigBoy1337: Almost, although maybe I could have been more clear. Basically, we're looking for an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/): a piece of code that you write completely isolated from your current project that replicates the original problem that you're having. In this case, it should contain the SQLAlchemy setup (engine creation), table definition, and then finally the code to run the query, change the object, and commit. See an example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19387882/how-to-make-sqlalchemy-return-float-instead-of-decimal-when-reflecting-tables).

Comment: Why not just make data your primary key? It will be auto incremented for you...

Comment: @MarkHildreth ok I have added the engine creation. I tried to make it isolated from my current project but there are certain things (like the table specifications and the radio button input) that are requirements to replicate the issue I am having.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok this was the problem. when I first called item1 and item2, it would randomly query the database with those random integers formulated in randoms.

but then when it gets to the line `item1.data+=1` it would try and randomly query again for item1. This means that no matter what the output was (right or left), it would again randomly pick an item from the database to add 1 to. aka inconsistent results.

In order to fix this, I had to separate my code into the GET and the POST cases as you can see below. Basically I created the two random "keys" in the GET method when the page is initially loaded. Then I passed the keys to the template

```
if request.method == "GET":


        length_table=session.query(func.count(Item.id)).scalar()
        randoms=random.sample(range(1,length_table+1),2)


        results = session.query(Item).filter(Item.id.in_(randoms)).all()


        return {'randoms':randoms,'item1':randoms[0],'item2':randoms[1],'results':results}
```

then on the template I put those key values into the form that the user submits as hidden values

```
<input type="hidden" name="item1" value=${item1}>
<input type="hidden" name="item2" value=${item2}>
```

finally, In the POST part, I pull in those values. This means that they are not re randomized, but instead are the same key values that the original items were queried with.

```
if request.method == "POST":

        key1=request.params['item1']
        key2=request.params['item2']
        randoms=[key1,key2]
        results = session.query(Item).filter(Item.id.in_(randoms)).all()
        if output == "left":
            results[0].data=results[0].data+1

            return HTTPFound(location=request.route_url('sorting'))

        if output == "right":
            results[1].data=results[1].data+1
            return HTTPFound(location=request.route_url('sorting'))
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not completely sure where your `item1` and `item2` are coming from, but I'm assuming you're initializing them somewhere prior to the logic you posted, something like:

```
item1 = DBSession.query(Item).filter(Item.id == passed_value).first()
```

If not, what are `item1` and `item2`?

Anyway, assuming you already have a valid `item1` object and want to update it, and you're using ZopeTransactionExtension I end up doing something like this:

```
if request.POST.get('myradiobutton') == "left":
    item1.data+=1
    DBSession.add(item1)
    DBSession.flush()
    return HTTPFound(location=request.route_url('sorting'))
```

Comment: It does make sense that I should add the item to the database session before flush commiting changes. However, your solution did not seem to fix the problem. Because I am using the pyramid framework, I have heard that I need to use transaction.commit(), though I do not completely understand why. Also, I have added the item definitions to the question so that you can see them.

Comment: Thank you! I'm relatively new to Pyramid as well, but I think the transaction.commit() is only needed if you aren't using  ZopeTransactionExtension; I based pretty much everything on [tutorials from the Pyramid site](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.4-branch/tutorials/wiki2/definingmodels.html#making-edits-to-models-py). Something like `DBSession = scoped_session(sessionmaker(extension=ZopeTransactionExtension()))` in your models declaration.